# Wordpress not recognising my custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes, wordpress-theming

I've been making a basic custom theme and everything was working fine. I had just finished pretty much styling everything in the blog section, left my computer for around 10 mins came back and it reverted back to the default twentyfourteen theme, claiming that my theme file was missing ('the template file'). I double checked and the file is still there so no idea what is going here?

This is what the top of my CSS looks like:

```
/*
Theme Name: AppTh.at
Theme URI: http://shjohnson.co.uk
Author: Samuel Johnson
Author URI: http://www.shjohnson.co.uk
Description: A simple theme developed to market AppTh.at's products
Version: 1.0

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
AppThat is part of the MonkeyFind Brand
*/
```

Someone mentioned trying to add 'Template: appth.at' but that didnt seem to do anything except show up the theme then when i tried to activate it, it said it was broken?

Answer (score 0):

How your directory structure should look like:

```
wp-content
    themes
        your-theme
            index.php
            style.css
```

Your CSS header looks fine, does your theme also has a index.php file? If not then you should add one this is required.

Adding `Template: appth.at` is not required, this is only needed when your creating a child theme, if you are then you should note the folder of the parent theme there. ie if you're creating a child theme for Twenty Eleven then you write: `Template: twentyeleven`

Comment: Thanks for this, although the problem was my style.css page was inside a folder called CSS. The style.css file has to be in the theme directory folder otherwise its not recognised. For some reason this worked for a while and i found that if i saved the file in the correct place then moved it manually it worked but if i updated the file then the above happened.

Comment: As you can see in the directory structure above. Please upvote & accept the answer if it's helpful. Welcome to the community :)

Answer (score -1):

First the obvious:

- you need to put the theme's folder in the WordPress theme directory
- you need to have a style.css and a index.php

That should do it, but there may be other problems of course (even though the theme should show on the theme page).

WordPress codex offers clear information on theming:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files

Comment: Thanks for this, although the problem was my style.css page was inside a folder called CSS. The style.css file has to be in the theme directory folder otherwise its not recognised. For some reason this worked for a while and i found that if i saved the file in the correct place then moved it manually it worked but if i updated the file then the above happened..